# Exclude a duplicate record from a view based on condtions and keep 1 - SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have three joined tables `Student`, `StudentTransportOrder` and `Transport` in SQL Server 2012.

I have created a `StudentActivity` view for this.

In the `StudentTransportOrder` table, each student record has a unique `TransportOrderID`.

When transport is ordered, `VehicleID` this is recorded into the `StudentTransportOrder` table.

Unfortunately the same `VehicleID` has been entered for the same date and time for a student records.

The `StudentActivity` view already returns records based on where conditions, but I also need to remove the duplicate records, preferably keep the records where if a student has used transport on the same date and time, that only one distinct VehicleID is returned and preferably the where the transport type is TransportVehicle = Car

How can I amend the view , without deleting records from the main tables, also bring back records even if no transport has been ordered

Please help

Comment: please explain along with some sample data and also paste expected result

Comment: To improve question,you can check this link :https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY StudentID,VehicleID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS PartitionedCount
```

... to your query and use a filter like `WHERE PartitionedCount=1`.

This will number your rows for each combination of Student and vehicle separately (you'll have to include the date or datetime probably).

You can use the `(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))` to force a car sorted on top...

### UPDATE

As I do not know your actual tables here's a general example:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,GroupID INT,SomeValue VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl(GroupID,SomeValue) VALUES
 (1,'val 1 for 1')
,(1,'val 2 for 1')
,(1,'val 3 for 1')
,(2,'val 1 for 2')
,(2,'val 2 for 2')
,(3,'val 1 for 3')
,(3,'val 2 for 3');

WITH Numbered AS
(
    SELECT tbl.*
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY GroupID ORDER BY ID /*DESC*/) AS Number 
    FROM @tbl AS tbl 
)
SELECT * FROM Numbered
WHERE Number=1
```

Try first without the `WHERE`. You will get all rows with partitioned numbering. Using the `WHERE` will reduce the output to the one with number `=1`.

It is on you to find a clever `ORDER BY` which brings your cars to the top (`CASE` will help you probably).

Just good to know: In my `ORDER BY` you find an inactive `DESC`. If you take away the `/**/` you can use the same approach to find the last row to a given sort order.

Comment: Hi I did try this method, as was unsuccessful.  Is there a way of if StudentID has two VehicleID (the same), only keep record with the TransportType as 'Car'  ??  please help

Comment: @pete, Please provide sample data and expected output. Use the edit option of your question to add this and your existing code. And please try to  be as specific as possible (reduced, but to the point): Statemets like *was unsuccessufl* don't tell anything to me. Error message? Syntax or runtime error? Or just not the expected result...

Comment: Hi  how can I use somthing like this within the view to keep the required record ?    SELECT VehicleID, COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.Student123
GROUP BY VehicleID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 but then keep the record where TransportType = 'Car'

Comment: @pete, Please do what I've asked you in my last comment. I'm not sitting beside you, do not have the information you have... No chance to help you...

Comment: I just need at the end of the view remove the records where if StudentTransportOrder has two instances of the same VehicleID, keep record of the VehicleType = Car...so when the view is out putted the duplicates are removed and ,master tables remain unaffected - please help